# How to find out which key has the same key in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging unit test

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

I'm using Enterprise Library's Semantic Logging. When I run my unit test:

```
EventSourceAnalyzer.InspectAll(MyEventSource.Log)
```

it fails, throwing an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

This is all good, but I made a bunch of Changes in the last check in. Is there a way to find out what key already have been added?

The app also fails with the same error message when I add my ObservableEventLister:

```
_logListener.EnableEvents(MyEventSource.Log, EventLevel.Verbose, Keywords.All)
```

**EDIT:**
I found the failing keys by commenting out different areas, but I can't see that those are duplicates. After cleaning the solution it all works. But... the question is still relevant. Is there an easy way to find the duplicate key other than the hacky way I had to do?